# Nextcloud and FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, nextcloud

I'm working on a FullCalendar project for my workplace.

At work we use Nextcloud and my boss asked me if there was a way to connect and sync the Nextcloud calendar to the FullCalendar project I'm building via HTML, JavaScript, PHP and phpMyAdmin.

I tried searching online but didn't find anything.

Can someone tell me if it's possible, please?

Comment: Well fullCalendar can load any events provided in the JSON format it specifies. It can also read from ics files (as per the documentation) as well has having a ready-made vendor-specific integration with Google Calendar. If your calendar doesn't output in either format specifically, it's usually not difficult to transform the data with a few lines of code. But without knowing anything about what type of data feed nextcloud's calendar provides - if any - it's difficult to suggest a precise solution.

Comment: Although, from a quick google, it seems that https://github.com/nextcloud/calendar is already built on top of fullCalendar, so it seems it must be possible. And it's open-source, so you can take a look yourself at exactly how they did it :-).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the suggestion and the link. I'm gonna look at it. and honeslty i'm scared, i'm new to all this stuff and learning from the internet and here on SO so guess good luck to me hahah

Comment: For me the question is what you actually mean by "sync" here ... You want to integrate all calendar entries into a single calendar? _Why?_ It is much more convenient to keep them apart and only show them in a combined view.